# Css transform in jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have img and I need to rotate it 90 degree when I click on it.

```
<img src="img/right-arrow.png" alt="" class="show">
```

when I use

```
.show {
transform: rotate(90deg); 
}
```

in Css file it works. 
but when I do it in jQuery it doesn't work. 
here is my code in jQuery

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform" : "rotate(90deg)");
}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you used a `:` in your function, use a comma instead:

```
$(this).css("-webkit-transform", "rotate(90deg)");
```

Answer (score 1):

see here **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mihai_T/w1sy9yyh/)**

if you want to use `:` in your css in JQ you need to put the whole code between `{}`

like so :

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(90deg)"});
}
);
```

OR if you don't want to use `{}` use `,` instead of `:` like so

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).css("-webkit-transform" , "rotate(90deg)");
}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.show').click(function(){
  $(this).css({
    '-moz-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
    '-webkit-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
    '-o-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
    '-ms-transform':'rotate(90deg)',
    'transform':'rotate(90deg)'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
$('.show').click(function(){
    $(this).css({"-webkit-transform" : "rotate(90deg)"});
}
);
```

[**DEMO HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/w1sy9yyh/1/)